# How to create an auto-reply to unknown senders in gmail?

Tags: gmail, automation

I want to send automated replies to emails I receive on my gmail account, if I haven't corresponded with the sender before. This basically mimics an out-of-office / vacation reply, but only triggers in case the sender is unknown to me.

From what I have seen in the settings of gmail, sending vacation replies to contacts is no problem. I can send such messages to everyone in my contact list, but it doesn't work the other way round.

If the solution requires me to add all whitelisted senders to my address book, this is OK, but I would prefer a solution that works based on my conversation history.

Comment: I think you would have to create a program that polls your gmail account with the Google API and then responds to emails how you want. If you have not done coding before this will be non-trivial.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. You could use [tag:google-apps-script] to automate some Gmail tasks. For further details, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Please bear in mind that asking for software recommendations is off-topic here, but if that is what you are looking for you could try [softwarerecs.se].